# what is the type of an angular strictly typed form value?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a FormGroup

```
protected appForm = this.formBuilder.nonNullable.group({
  domain: ['', Validators.required],
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  description: [''],
});
```

in ngOnInit I fill it with data:

```
const formValue = {} as Record<string, any>;
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.appl)) {
  if (key === '_id') {
    const [domain, name] = value.split(this.SEPERATOR);
    formValue["name"] = value;
    formValue["domain"] = value;
  } else  {
    formValue[key] = value;
  }
}
this.appForm.setValue(formValue as ValueType); // what type here?
```

}

I know, that formValue has the right fields, so I want to cast it to the required type.
But what is the type? I do not want to define it by hand, I want to generate it from
the type of this.appForm. Something like:

```
this.appForm.setValue(formValue as ReturnType<typeof this.appForm.value>);
```

Comment: If you are confident the fields are right, you could use`as ReturnType<typeof this.appForm.*getRawValue*>;`. `formGroup.value` returns a `Partial<...>` as it omits disabled fields. `getRawValue()` includes disabled fields, thus the type it returns is the whole FormGroup type, and not a partial.